# Nginx removes post data with content-type header

Tags: nginx, http-headers, json

I am making posts like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost/api.php' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data 'names=[{"name":"name"}]'
```

Which results in the post data being deleted.

If I remove the content-type header, e.g.

```
curl 'http://localhost/api.php' --data 'names=[{"name":"name"}]'
```

The post data is present.

The Nginx congiuraiton consists of this:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;
root /var/www/;

server_name _;

location ~ \.php$
{
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
}   

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    index index.html; 
    autoindex on;
}
}
```

Does anyone have any insight into why this is?

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is Nginx's doing. Try

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 'names=[{"name":"name"}]' 'http://localhost/api.php'
```

PHP does receive the json data, but the only way I could retrieve it, was

```
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    var_dump($json);
```

which gave

```
string(23) "names=[{"name":"name"}]"
```

Even phpinfo() would not show the data, only the headers type and content size.

I had forgotten about [GeekForGeeks howto](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggest. The same error occurs. Do you think it may be PHP? It is nothing to do with any code as I tried printing the POST before any other code.

Comment: I am getting this on both my local (dev) and remote (live) server. The Nginx config for them is not the same.

Comment: Replace api.php by a page containing nothing but a phpinfo();.  Then you'll see what PHP receives.  Alternatively, let php-fpm listen on a tcp port iso. a socket.  Then run tcpdump on that port.  If the data isn't there, run tcpdump on port 80.  This way you obtain proof of where the data is lost.

Comment: See my edited answer.